# mongodb is not defined. Help setting up MEAN stack

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

```
ReferenceError: mongodb is not defined
    at C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\routes\index.js:11:21
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (C:\Users\john\meantut\sampsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
```

So I'm following this tutorial (http://www.newthinktank.com/2016/01/mean-stack-tutorial/) on setting up the mean stack and I'm at point number 12 on setting up mongodb. This point is just to check if the mongo server and the other components are working together however for me they are not as I'm getting this error. Any advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated as I've tried about 10 different MEAN stack tutorials with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in that tutorial:

> 8. In the app.js file add the line
>
> var ***mongo*** = require('mongodb'); after the bodyParser line

The var is `mongo`.
It calls it with:

> // Get a Mongo client to work with the Mongo server
>
> var MongoClient = ***mongodb***.MongoClient;

Change the one or the other to match.